# Spark job with custom Docker image from private registry

Tags: apache-spark, docker, mesos

I would like to build a custom Docker image that can be used with Spark's spark.mess.executor.docker.image configuration option.  This image will contain private information so it would need to be kept in a private registry.  Is this possible?  I don't see any documented way to specify login credentials as part of the spark-submit command.

Answer (score 1):

It seems I should be to specify the URL to a docker credentials file as part of the spark.mesos.uris spark-submit option.

Comment: Could you provide some more specific documentation about that here so that if somebody else finds your question they don't then have to go digging for the details?

Comment: http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/running-on-mesos.html see the part referring to the option spark.mesos.uris.

Comment: @MitchMcCuiston Thanks